# Validación de un atributo fecha en Rails en tablas relacionadas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo dos modelos en Rails, uno es *Trabajador* y el otro *Asistencia*. Un trabajador puede tener muchas asistencias y cada asistencia es de un solo trabajador. Necesito que al agregar una asistencia a un trabajador, la fecha sea única (por día). Probé con `validates :fecha, uniqueness:true` en el modelo *Asistencia*, pero no sirve ya que me deja crear una asistencia para x trabajador, pero al querer agregar otra asistencia a un trabajador diferente con la misma fecha, no me deja, porque coloqué que fuera sea única. Necesito que ese atributo sea único por dia solo para cada trabajador.

Modelo Asistencia

```
class Assistance < ActiveRecord::Base
`belongs_to :worker
validates :fecha, uniqueness: true `
```

Tablas:

```
create_table "assistances", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "worker_id"
t.boolean  "asistio"
t.boolean  "excepcion"
t.date     "fecha"
t.integer  "horas"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

create_table "workers", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "nombre"
t.integer  "rut"
t.text     "direccion"
t.string   "telefono"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "equipo"
t.string   "jefe"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "boss_id"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que te parece si pruebas usando scope, reemplazando:

`validates :fecha, uniqueness: true`

por

`validates :fecha, uniqueness: { scope: [:worker_id] }`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió,  no conocía scope